# orientation layout tutorial incomplete

Tags: android

i' m a newbie, 
Can anyone guide me how to change code below with the [image] i upload, i'm really confused, since I have no idea how to change the current code.

the image i try to achieve [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl8L9.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl8L9.jpg) but current image is [current image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNeIh.jpg)
i tried few method like changing the orientation or layout of height, but it still remains the same

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Team A" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="addThreeForTeamA"
        android:text="+3 Points" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="addTwoForTeamA"
        android:text="+2 Points" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="addOneForTeamA"
        android:text="Free throw" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Team B" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="addThreeForTeamA"
        android:text="+3 Points" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="addTwoForTeamA"
        android:text="+2 Points" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="addOneForTeamA"
        android:text="Free throw" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sorry for my broken english, the image above is the result i want to achieve, but so far i m stucking here

Comment: Why are the two linear layouts inside the top level linear layout empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:weightSum="2"
 android:orientation="horizontal">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="Team A" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="0" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:onClick="addThreeForTeamA"
    android:text="+3 Points" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:onClick="addTwoForTeamA"
    android:text="+2 Points" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:onClick="addOneForTeamA"
    android:text="Free throw" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="Team B" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="0" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:onClick="addThreeForTeamA"
    android:text="+3 Points" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:onClick="addTwoForTeamA"
    android:text="+2 Points" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:onClick="addOneForTeamA"
    android:text="Free throw" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks dude, btw any tips to share me , if want learn more in android developer? like learning jaya ? or what else i need to learn

Comment: Android java is quite easy compared to core java.
Learn basics about xml and how to bind views and set on click listeners in item.
And accept my ans if u find it appropriate :)

Comment: sure, Nice answer, Thanks dude